# Custom Material Style not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design, android-styles

I have an app with min sdk 18 that works fine without the material theme style but when i put a material style in values-v21 the app just crashes as soon as its launched. I've confirmed that this is the cause of the crash.

I've seen solutions for the Holo styles where you have to use the Base.AppCompat.Holo.Dark as a parent. Is there something similar for Material?

I've attached the styles.xml from the values-v21 directory below. Please ask if you need any more info.

Android Studio 1.2 on Windows 8.1 Testing on a OnePlus One

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: `android:Theme.Material` is applicable only for API Level 21+. Use `AppCompat` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AppCompat instead of Material

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Theme :

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Set AppCompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. Would customising the rest of the elements be the same as how i would do it if my min SDK level was 21?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a section on the android developers page. [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) . Thanks